# SQLite: last_insert_rowid() in same INSERT statement

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, pdo, sql-insert

I running this query in PHP/SQLite 3 (PDO)

Scenario: a new driver is inserted into drivers table and an existing car is immediately linked to him:

DRIVERS

- driver_id [PK]
- driver_name

CARS

- car_id [PK]
- fk_driver_id [FK]

  $qr = "INSERT INTO drivers (driver_name) VALUES ('{$_GET['driver_name']}'); COMMIT; UPDATE cars SET fk_driver_id=( SELECT last_insert_rowid() ) WHERE car_id={$_GET['car_id']};";
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($qr);
  $result = $stmt->execute();

It inserts the driver but does not UPDATE the cars table and produces no error either.

It works if I use the same query using SQLite Spy.

In PHP it will only if I break it in two parts:

```
$qr = "INSERT INTO drivers (driver_name) VALUES ('{$_GET['driver_name']}'); COMMIT; ";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($qr);
$result = $stmt->execute();

$qr = "UPDATE cars SET fk_driver_id=( SELECT last_insert_rowid() ) WHERE car_id={$_GET['car_id']};";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($qr);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

What is wrong in the PHP code if it won't work in one single statement?

Comment: print the sql statements sent to execute to be sure they are what you believe. The only reason I can see for the update not to work is the WHERE condition

Comment: Are you sure that executing multiple statements with a single `execute` is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
$qr = "INSERT INTO drivers (driver_name) VALUES ('{$_GET['driver_name']}'); ";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($qr);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
$dbh->commit();

$qr = "UPDATE cars SET fk_driver_id=? WHERE car_id={$_GET['car_id']};";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($qr);
$result = $stmt->execute(array($lastId));
```